# What are the scriptural sources for the worship of Shiva in Murti form?

Tags: vedas, shiva, puranas, worship, agamas

Worship of Shiva in Linga form is widely practiced. But in some places Murti Pooja is done in temples too. Is it a valid practice? What are the scriptural sources from Vedas/Puranas/Shaivaagamas about Murti Pooja of Shiva with or without the consort?

Answer (score 2):

One does not have to worship Shiva in the linga form. Any form would do.

> Henceforth, I shall mention the benefit accruing from the installation
> of the idol entirely, for the welfare of the world. **The idol may be in
> accordance with one’s own wish.**

**Linga Purana I.76.1**

> After making **the idol of the lord seated in an elegant seat** along with
> the Skanda and Uma and after installing it with devotion one shall
> fulfil desires.

**Linga Purana I.76.2**